# free-jqGrid 4.15.6 ExpandNode producing runtime error

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I recently upgraded from the original Tony Tomov's jqGrid v4.5.4 to Oleg's free-jqGrid 4.15.6.

When using 4.5.4, the code below worked perfect, but in 4.15.6, it does not.  The run-time error is produced by the two calls to expandNode and expandRow located in the forceNodeOpen() function. The error given:

TypeError: rc1 is undefined

The forceNodeOpen() function is used to force all ancestor nodes of the current treegrid node to show as expanded.  Much like a table of contents...if we load an initial topic node, we want the whole topic hierarchy to be expanded:

```
// force a node (if expandable) to stay expanded
function forceNodeOpen(rowid)
{
    var record = $("#tree").jqGrid('getRowData', rowid);
    var div = $('tr#'+rowid).find('div.ui-icon.treeclick');
    div.removeClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-e tree-plus').addClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-s tree-minus');
    **$('#tree').jqGrid('expandNode', record);**    
    **$('#tree').jqGrid('expandRow', record);**

    // get all ancestoral parents and expand them
    // *NOTE*: the getAncestorNodes function of grid was not usable for 
    //         some reason as the same code below just would not work 
    //         with the return array from getAncestorNodes
    var parent = $("#tree").jqGrid('getNodeParent', record);
    while(parent)
    {
        forceNodeOpen(parent['id']);
        parent = $("#tree").jqGrid('getNodeParent', parent);
    }
}

// using topic url, get the tree row id
function getTopicID(topic)
{
    var nodes = $('#tree').jqGrid('getRowData');
    var rowid = 1;
    $.each(nodes, function(e,i)
    {
        var url = $(this).attr('url');
        if(url == topic)
        {
            rowid = $(this).attr('id');
            return false;
        }
    });

    return rowid;
}

// post request to help server via ajax
function loadTopic(topic)
{
    // no need to load again
    if(loadedtopic == topic) { return false; }

    // select the topic node
    var rowid = getTopicID(topic);
    loading = true;
    $('#tree').jqGrid('setSelection', rowid);
    forceNodeOpen(rowid);
    loading = false;

    // wipe content
    $('h1#help_content_topic span:first').html('Loading...');
    $('div#help_content').html('');

    // block UI for ajax posting
    blockInterface();

    // request help content
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST', 
        url: '/index.php',
        data: { 'isajax': 1, 'topic': topic },
        success: function(data)
        { 
            $.unblockUI();
            $('h1#help_content_topic span:first').html(data['topic']);
            $('div#help_content').html(data['content']);
            return false;
        }
    });

    // save current topic to prevent loading same topic again
    loadedtopic = topic;
}

// table of contents
$('#tree').jqGrid({
    url: "topics.php",
    datatype: "xml",
    autowidth: true,
    caption: "Help Topics",
    colNames: ["id","","url"],
    colModel: [
        {name: "id",width:1,hidden:true, key:true},
        {name: "topic", width:150, resizable: false, sortable:false},
        {name: "url",width:1,hidden:true}
    ],
    ExpandColClick: true,
    ExpandColumn: 'topic',
    gridview: false,
    height: 'auto',
    hidegrid: false,
    pager: false,
    rowNum: 200,
    treeGrid: true,
    treeIcons: {leaf:'ui-icon-document-b'},

    // auto-select topic node
    gridComplete: function()
    {
        // save current topic to prevent loading same topic again
        loadedtopic = '<? echo($topic) ?>';
        var rowid = getTopicID('<? echo($topic) ?>');
        $('#tree').jqGrid('setSelection', rowid);
        forceNodeOpen(rowid);
        $.unblockUI();
    },

    // clear initial loading
    loadComplete: function()
    {
        loading = false;
    },

    onSelectRow: function(rowid)
    {
        // ignore initial page loads
        if(loading) { return false; }

        // load the selected topic
        var topic = $("#tree").jqGrid('getCell',rowid,'url');
        loadTopic(topic);
    }
});
```

The forceNodeOpen(rowid) is invoked from the loadTopic() function, which is called inside the onSelectRow() event of the treegrid.

Not sure what 4.5.4 did that allowed this code to work but 4.15.6 finds it to be an error.  The offending line in 4.15.6.src.js:

```
expandNode: function (rc) { 
...
if (p.treedatatype !== "local" && !base.isNodeLoaded.call($($t), p.data[p._index[id]]) && !$t.grid.hDiv.loading) {
// set the value which will be used during processing of the server response
// in readInput
p.treeANode = rc1.rowIndex;
p.datatype = p.treedatatype;
...});
```

I have only included a few lines from the above core function.  It's the p.treeANode = rc1.rowIndex that throws the error.

I have to be missing something but do not know what.  Hoping somebody can tell me what to do.  If I remark out the two expandNode and expandRow treegrid function calls in forceNodeOpen() function, the system does not error out and the desired topic loads.  But the hierarchy is not expanded as desired.

---

START EDIT 1

---

The server-side code that returns the topic nodes:

```
echo("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n");

require('db.php');

echo("<rows>\n");
echo("<page>1</page>\n");
echo("<total>1</total>\n");
echo("<records>1</records>\n");

$sql = "SELECT node.id, node.parentid, node.topic, node.url, node.lft, node.rgt, (COUNT(node.parentid) - 1) AS depth 
            FROM helptopics AS node, helptopics AS parent 
                WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
                    GROUP BY node.url ORDER BY node.lft";
$stmt = AMDB::selectStatement($sql);
while($data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $id = $data['id'];
    $pid = $data['parentid'];
    $topic = $data['topic'];
    $url = $data['url'];
    $lft = $data['lft'];
    $rgt = $data['rgt'];
    $leaf = $rgt - $lft == 1 ? 'true' : 'false';
    $exp = 'false';
    $dep = $data['depth'];

    echo("<row><cell>{$id}</cell><cell>{$topic}</cell><cell>{$url}</cell><cell>{$dep}</cell><cell>{$lft}</cell><cell>{$rgt}</cell><cell>{$leaf}</cell><cell>{$exp}</cell></row>\n");
}

echo("</rows>\n");
exit();
```

---

END EDIT 1

---

Comment: could you post some demo (in jsfiddle, for example), which reproduces the problem? I suppose that you don't removed columns `level`, `parent`, `isLeaf`, `expanded`, `loaded`, `icon` from `colModel`. Free jqGrid introduced so named "additional properties", where the properties be saved in local data, but not in hidden `<td>` elements of the grid. See [the old post](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/additionalProperties-option-makes-unneeded-hidden-columns-in-local-scenario)

Comment: I posted the whole javascript.  The only hidden columns are 'id' and 'url' and they are not causing any errors (console.logging and alerts confirmed).  The exact offending line is within the source code jquery.jqGrid.5.15.6.src.js, line 19415.  I am not sure how to create this in jsFiddle.  The only code I did not include in the question is the PHP script that loads the tree.  I have added that to question...

Comment: You can look at [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.15.5/js/grid.treegrid.js#L401) of the code of `expandNode`, which shows how `rc1` will be initialized. You get `undefined` value with your dame data. Thus there is a problem with *input data*, which you use to call `expandNode`. I can analyse the problem only if I can reproduce it. I don't need any server code, which generate the data. It's enough to have the data as text file. I need just to have small demo, which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I thought that too.  But I put a console.log(rc1) right under line 14907 rc1 = .... and I get the expexted <tr id='....'>.... result.  But 8 lines down on 14915, rc1 is all of a sudden undefined.

Comment: @oleg, if you PM me, I will be happy to give you a live link to the production code.  Then you can see how it is used, and maybe then you can help me find my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you use

```js
var record = $("#tree").jqGrid('getRowData', rowid);
```

to get node data of TreeGrid. It wasn't good, but it worked in old jqGrid because it saved internal jqGrid data **twice**: once as local data and once more time in hidden cells of the grid.

You should use `getLocalRow` instead of `getRowData`:

```js
var record = $("#tree").jqGrid('getLocalRow', rowid);
```

The code will work on both old jqGrid and free jqGrid. Additionally, `getLocalRow` has always better performance comparing with `getRowData` even in jqGrid 4.5.4.

Comment: You are welcome! I'd recommend you to search in the code for `getRowData` and to use `getLocalRow` if you use it with rowid parameter. Instead of usage `getRowData` without parameters you can use `$('#tree').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data')`. The method `getRowData` without parameter enumerate all `<td>` elements of the grid, read the content of DOM and unformat the data. The method `$('#tree').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data')` just return the reference to object with array of data, where already all filled.

Comment: @Chance: You can additionally **remove** unneeded hidden "id" and "url" columns from `colModel` and to use `additionalProperties: ["url"]` instead. The *local JavaScript data* (returned by `getLocalRow` or `.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data')`) will contains `url` (`id` is saved by default) and you can access it directly. It will additionally improve the performance of TreeGrid and will reduced memory used for the page.

Comment: I tried removing the id, and url from colModel as you suggest.  I had to modify colNames[] to match new colModel[] and added additionalProperties["url"], I get weird result of all nodes being just IDs, and all randomly expanded/collapsed. .  The tree stops working altogether.

Comment: @Chance: I see that you use `XML` format with `repeatitems: true` order (nodes without names, where **the order** of items defines the column). In the case converting of columns in properties will be a little more complex. The most easy way would be if you will return JSON instead of XML. It will improve performance of parsing the data. To do that you will need to replace first lines strarting with `echo("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n");`, ... to one symbol `[`. Every line should look like `{"id":"{$id}", "topic":"{$topic}", "url":"{$url}", "level": "{$dep}", "lft": "{$lft}"},,,}`

Comment: @Chance: You need just fill *by name* all properties, which you need to display TreeGrid plus `level`, `lft`, `rgt`, `isLeaf`, `expanded`. You can validate correctness of test JSON data in https://jsonlint.com/. You need of cause replace `datatype: "xml"` to `datatype: "json"` too. Alternatively you can provide some *test XML data* which returns your server and I'll help you to add `xmlmap` properties to read the data. The usage of JSON is *recommended way*, but XML is supported too. It's slowly of course, but it works with using corresponding options.